# Sysprep was not able to validate Windows Installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, deployment, sysprep, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I have been trying to capture an image of a Windows 10 Pro x64. I get the error message `Sysprep was not able to validate Windows Installation` and a report with errors as pasted below. I have about 20 Surfaces 4 Pro to deploy the image to.

The errors:

> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error                 SYSPRP Package
>   89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w was installed
>   for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not
>   function properly in the sysprep image.
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove
>   apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of
>   RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP
>   ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing
>   'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll;
>   dwRet = 0x3cf2
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error                 SYSPRP
>   SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from
>   C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error                 SYSPRP
>   RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating SysprepSession actions;
>   dwRet = 0x3cf2
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An
>   error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep
>   execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
>
> 2017-08-08 12:38:35, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure
>   while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr =
>   0x80073cf2

Comment: Try opening a command prompt (or PowerShell) window and execute **slmgr /dlv**.  Within the ensuing window, check the `Remaining Windows rearm count` to ensure that it says at least **1**

Comment: @Run5k I checked and it indicates 1001.

Comment: What command did you run exactly?  What user are you using?  If you are using something other than the built-in account that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of that error log is the key. Microsoft has [a support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2769827/sysprep-fails-after-you-remove-or-update-windows-store-apps-that-inclu) describing this problem. First, you need to uninstall the Universal Windows Platform app mentioned in the error. To do that, search for it in the Start menu (it's probably called something along the lines of "Autodesk SketchBook"), and if it's found, right-click it and choose Uninstall. Reboot, and try to run Sysprep again.

If that doesn't help, run this command in an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | ? {$_.PackageFullName -eq '89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w'}
```

Look at the `PackageUserInformation` property. If any users have the package `Installed`, destroy the user account if it is not needed, otherwise log in as the user and uninstall it. If you can't do that, use this command to remove the package for all users:

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package '89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w' -AllUsers
```

Reboot and try again.

If Sysprep still refuses to continue, you need to unprovision the package (that Microsoft article says that Sysprep "will also fail if an all-user package that's provisioned into the image was updated by one of the users on this reference computer"):

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName '89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w'
```

You might also check the log file again if the failure remains - Sysprep might start complaining about a different package that also needs to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I greatly appreciate it.  The problem when i run this command, i see a user that i cannot use it as an account to login.  The package user information is: {s-1-5-21-1968875819-78012282-1250455498-1001 [s-1-5-21-1968875819-78012282-1250455498-1001]: Installed}
What do you think?  I also tried to unprovision using the command provided, not working!

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. How exactly does the unprovisioning command fail? (If the error message won't fit in a comment, you can edit it into the question.)

Comment: @AnsBekk You might want to try the unprovisioning command with the `-AllUsers` switch added. Also try `Remove-AppxPackage -Package '89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w' -AllUsers`.

Comment: Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName '89006A2E.Autodesk ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.RemoveAppxProvisionedPackageCommand

Comment: I will try what you just suggested

Comment: What value should I assign when I run -Allusers?? Here is what I get:
cmdlet Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage at command pipeline position 1

Supply values for the following parameters:

Online:

Comment: @AnsBekk With this command, we're just using `Remove-AppxPackage`, not `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage`, so it shouldn't need an `-Online` switch.

Comment: I ran this command:
 Remove-AppxPackage -PackageName '89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64_tf1gferkr813w'
I got this error message:

Remove-AppxPackage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PackageName'.

Comment: @AnsBekk Right, for `Remove-AppxPackage`, the parameter name is just `-Package`. Also make sure to include the `-AllUsers` switch. (You can copy the full command from my earlier comment.)

Comment: looks like it worked. let me try sysprep and see if the error message disappear at least for that App.  Thank you for you help.

Comment: The operation completed, but errors were encountered.
For additional information, look in Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeployment/Operational in the Event Log.
Any thoughts?  This is after I ran the command for the second time, and the error message still occurs when I run sysprep and the packageapp is still installed!!

Comment: @AnsBekk Strange. Does the Sysprep log still refer to the same package? Also consult that Event Log section (run `eventvwr.msc` to launch Event Viewer) to see if there are any relevant error messages. If the computer hasn't been rebooted since the package removal, you might try that.

Comment: Yes it refers to the same package.  I am going to reboot and check eventvwr.

Comment: Here is the error message at the event viewer:
Failed to queue removal of package 89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.5.2.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w for user S-1-5-21-1968875819-78012282-1250455498-1001 with error: 0x80070005.

Comment: @AnsBekk I believe the AppX system is confused about whether the account that SID refers to is deleted. In `regedit`, navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore` ([source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15057-clear-reset-store-cache-windows-10-a.html)). If it has a subkey named *exactly* the same as what you got from the `Get-AppxPackage` command previously, try renaming that subkey, rebooting, and trying Sysprep again.

Comment: There are two name keys:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\S-1-5-21-2638332139-3718812912-2522024971-4404. ======and======== HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\S-1-5-21-2638332139-3718812912-2522024971-6757.    None of them is the same, but they start with similar title which is S-1-5-21

Comment: @AnsBekk Unfortunately, neither of those are what we're looking for. [cew176's answer here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5e7c8439-bf9a-4050-8fbd-b2c207eb7b52/how-to-delete-an-app-from-a-deleted-users-account?forum=win10itprogeneral) claims to have fixed that person's problem, but it involves the deletion of some system bookkeeping and therefore might be dangerous (I haven't tested it). If you have a full back-up of the system, you might try that. Other than that, I'm about out of ideas - sorry :/

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.  I will use our comments for another computer.  I am going to do a fresh install with a single account in it (primary account) without deleting any other account.  I will install the programs I need to be captured in the image and then go from there.  Thank you again and have a wonderful weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved this issue,

I have deployed fresh windows 10 build 1709,

- Disable Windows Apps store,
  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-windows-store-application
- reboot.
- Remove default pre-installed Appx for all users,
  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/erase-default-preinstalled-modern-apps-windows-8
- Perform windows updates
- Install required applications.
- Perform sysprep

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Where PackageFullName -eq 89006A2E.AutodeskSketchBook_1.8.1.0_x64__tf1gferkr813w| Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers